# Why Google Cloud Console give No result found for Android Device Verification Api

Tags: firebase

I follow these steps in google cloud console :-

**Google Cloud Console-> Select Our project -> Select API & Services -> Select Enable API & Services -> Search Android Device Verification API ->** it gives "**No Result Found**"

why it gives this message while I want to enable **Android Device Verification API** feature. By Default **Android Device Verification API** does not show in API List on page **Enable API & Services** page and i want to include this feature in our project.

For another project when I search "**Android Device Verification API**" with above process it gives following error:-

**There was an error while loading /apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=chatme-342307. Please try again**.

**Request ID: 9929714032143206958**

Kindly support above two problems.

Answer (score 6):

Google has Depricated the Android Device Verification API so now you can use Google Play integrity API for the verification of Device.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the app from the project settings of my app in Firebase console. Then I recreated the app in the project settings and add it with both SHA1 and SHA256. Afterwards, searching for *Android Device Verification* makes it show up in the results.